# Laravel / AWS S3 - How to validate a file being uploaded using a Pre-Signed URL

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, validation, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

How does one validate files uploaded straight to S3 using a Pre-Signed URL?

Normally when uploading through Laravel, you can just validate the request using rules, such as:

```
[
    'image' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,png,pdf|max:2500',
]
```

However when using a Pre-Signed URL, the file goes straight to the S3 storage and Laravel only receives a string for the path or URL to the file/image.

Is there a way to determine rules when creating the S3 Pre-Signed URL for them to only accept certain files? Or can I get the Laravel app to retrieve the file from S3 storage afterwards and validate it using the same Validation rules?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your web app, there are no additional parameters to limit file type and such (as of now). You could implement additional client-side validation (which could help but most likely won't solve the problem).

However, you could use S3 policy statements to [limit file types](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-allow-certain-file-types/) and other things:

> - Allow the s3:PutObject action only for objects that have the extension of the file type that you want
> - Explicitly deny the s3:PutObject action for objects that don't have the extension of the file type that you want Note: You need this
>   explicit deny statement to apply the file-type requirement to users
>   with full access to your Amazon S3 resources. The following example
>   bucket policy allows the s3:PutObject action only for objects with
>   .jpg, .png, or .gif file extensions.
>
> Important: For the first Principal value, list the Amazon Resource
> Names (ARNs) of the users that you want to grant upload permissions
> to. For the Resource and NotResource values, be sure to replace
> bucket-name with the name of your bucket.
>
> ```
> {
>   "Version": "2012-10-17",
>   "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
>   "Statement": [
>     {
>       "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Principal": {
>         "AWS": "IAM-USER-ARN"
>       },
>       "Action": "s3:PutObject",
>       "Resource": [
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.jpg",
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.png",
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.gif"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
>       "Effect": "Deny",
>       "Principal": "*",
>       "Action": "s3:PutObject",
>       "NotResource": [
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.jpg",
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.png",
>         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.gif"
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Another thing is to use [CORS to specify the allowed origin](https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d).

Comment: Will this purely just check the extension name of the file, or does it actually try to check the content type of the file?